# Практическое применение std::string_view

Tags: c++

Мне понятно, что  `std::string_view`  это  строка, имеющая только указатель и длину, без владения, управления памятью и даже без завершающего нуля — и поэтому она не имеет функции `c_str()`. Но не смог разобраться(найти пример), когда он может быть предпочтительней или удобней  `std::string`? Если не затруднит, прошу ответить с примером.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Проблема, которую решает `std::string_view` - это проблема, которая при работе с `std::string` всплывает практически каждую секунду. Когда речь идет о немодифицирующих операциях над строками, в 9 случаях из 10 нам не нужны функции, работающие со всей строкой. Нам нужны более общие функции: работающие с какой-то *подстрокой* данного `std::string`, т.е. с каким-то поддиапазоном символов внутри строки.

Для этого, конечно, можно предварительно выделять из `std::string` интересующую нас подстроку, например вызовом `substr`, с формированием отдельного объекта типа `std::string`. И далее уже работать с выделенной подстрокой. Но создание подстроки в виде отдельного объекта `std::string` - это исключительно неэффективно и расточительно. Вот тут-то и приходит на помощь `std::string_view`, которая является "виртуальным окном" в существующую строку. Т.е. `std::string_view` реализует *виртуальное* выделение подстроки в строке, без дополнительного выделения памяти и копирования данных.

Фактически, общее правило таково: в вашей программе почти не должно быть функций с параметром типа `const std::string &`. Почти все такие функции должны принимать именно `const std::string_view &` или `std::string_view`. То есть вся функциональность немодифицирующей  обработки строк должна быть реализована именно в терминах `std::string_view`. А уж привязать это `std::string_view` вы можете и ко всей строке, и к любой ее подстроке. Это позволяет нам унифицировать константную обработку строк и подстрок без лишних затрат производительности и ресурсов.

То, что `std::string_view` можно "прицеплять" не только к строкам `std::string`, но и к обычным C-строкам - это еще одна дополнительная ценнейшая функциональность `std::string_view`. То есть `std::string_view` позволяет нам не только унифицировать строки с подстроками, но еще и унифицировать константную обработку `std::string` строк с C-строками.

Comment: Кто бы не понел после такого ответа?...

Answer (score 1):

Если вам в функцию требуется передать строку без копирования ее целиком, и в этой функции вы можете заменить ее на string_view, то лучше использовать именно ее. Все дело в том, что если вы передаёте в эту функцию не std::string, а указатель на char. В случае использования std::string (даже константной ссылки) будет создан полноценный объект, а строка полностью скопирована. В случае string_view никакого копирования не произойдет.